# Did Rav Hutner zt'l write any seforim?

Tags: tzaddikim

Did R' Hutner zt'l write any seforim that are available to buy? I'm not really seeing anything when searching

Comment: Toras HaNazir - more conventional lomdus from his early days. Pachad Yitzchak on Jewish thought -- multiple volumes on each of the holidays. If someone says they're studying the thought of R' Hutner, they mean Pachad Yitzchak.

Comment: e.g. https://www.eichlers.com/seforim/pachad-yzchak-h-yom-kipu-kipur-hs2382.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's been translated into English anywhere?

Comment: The style is sufficiently challenging that it's quite difficult to do a word-for-word translation, and his textual style means it just wouldn't come across right anyhow. But you can find stuff in English based on the teachings; e.g. here's Rabbi Stolper "interpreting and adapting" the Chanukah essays: https://www.eichlers.com/chanukah-in-a-new-light-pachad-yitzchak-ibsl297.html

Answer (score 2):

He personally wrote and authored  two Seforim. Toras Hanozir which you can buy here

[https://www.amazon.com/Sefer-HaNazir-Hebrew-Yitzhak-Hutner/dp/B00G2SW476](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G2SW476)

He also  wrote  a commentary on Rabbeinu Hillel's commentary on Toras Kohnim that was anonymous at the time of printing but well known as his sefer today. Most printed editions of Rabbeinu Hillel's commentary on Toras Kohnim include his commentary.

There is also a many volume Pachad Yitzcok on Yom Tovim which he wrote the outline for but  was edited by his son in law Rabbi Yonasan David ( allegedly with together  his wife, Bruriah, Rav Hutner's daughter) . There is one volume of it that is  called Igores U'Ksavim (letters and writings) that were written by him personally, thought he never published them in sefer form.

You can get the Pachad Yitzcok in many seforim stores or by contacting Chaim Berlin directly

Comment: The challenge with Rav Hutner's letters, as I'm told, is that it reflects only his responses -- those who received letters from him submitted them to the editors years later. He doesn't restate the question, the circumstances, or the addressee. (Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, for contrast, includes all of that information. Before he sent a response, he'd make a copy of the entire thing in a notebook, for later publication.)